# Xelatex / Fontspec how to load fonts directly from diskfile (Postscript Type 1 fonts)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have a directory containing a Type 1 Sabon font I want to use in Xelatex. I want to use the font by specifying the filenames using the `fontspec` package. I specifically define the bold and italic fonts as suggested in the fontspec manual. `\setmainfont` can take the same options as `\fontspec`, so I write:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, BCOR=0mm, DIV=default]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{xunicode}
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
   \setmainfont[Path=C:/fonts/, BoldFont=LTe50385.pfb ,ItalicFont=LTe50383.pfb]    
    {LTe50383.pfb}
            \begin{document}
            etc
            \end{document}
```

After trying to compile this i get the following errors

```
Font \zf@basefont="[C:/fonts/LTe50383.pfb ]/IC

    U" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font n
    ot found.
    <to be read again> 
                       \scan_stop: 
    l.7 ..., ItalicFont = LTe50383.pfm]{LTe50383.pfm }

    I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
    so I will ignore the font specification.
    [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
    You might try inserting a different font spec;
```

- Because of the error above I wonder if it is at all possible to load a Type 1 (Postscript) font in this way or is it restricted to OpenType and others. since it keeps asking for the TFM metric files. The Type 1 Metric files (.pfm) are placed in the same directory, but how does fontspec know how to use those?
- Or Am I doing something else wrong?

All help is much appreciated!

---

**Edit 1**

I'm able to use the fonts I want after installing them on the windows machine. However, this is not something I prefer, as at my workcomputer I'm unable to install fonts properly.
So this problem is directly related to using the fonts by loading the diskfiles.

---

**Edit 2**

The following test returns without errors:

```
\begin{document}
\font\test="[C:/fonts/LTe50383.pfb]" \test abc \par
\font\test="[C:/fonts/LTe50384.pfb]" \test abc \par
\font\test="[C:/fonts/LTe50385.pfb]" \test abc \par
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit 3**

It seems Xelatex automatically tries to find the best replacements for the unloadable font that are loaded on the machine, therefore giving some confusing false-positive results when trying to load fonts from diskfile directly using:

```
\setmainfont[Path=C:/fonts/, BoldFont=LTe50385.pfb ,ItalicFont=LTe50383.pfb]    
        {LTe50383.pfb}
```

---

**Edit 4**

Owhman, this is getting confusing :) It seems syntax related, as the tests in Edit 2, meaning that Type 1 fonts can be loaded using diskfiles. Who helps me correct my syntax?

---

**Edit 5**

The following works fine

```
\setmainfont[Path=C:/fonts/]{LTe50383.pfb}
```

and also using the diskfile to set a fontfamily works without problems:

```
\newfontfamily\scfont[Path=C:/fonts/]{SARSC___.PFB}
```

Meaning that I seem to be doing something wrong, and I shouldnt add fontfeatures such as BoldFont = and ItalicFont = to the \setmainfont option. Or should this be possibly and is this a bug in fontspec?

Comment: Seems to be working for me; what version of XeTeX/fontspec are you using?

Comment: Although I've never tested fontspec with PostScript fonts before; I see that some things aren't working so well/at all.

Comment: In theory xetex can use type1 fonts directly but I don't know for sure if it can handle pfm or if it needs an afm. At first I would try to install the fonts in the windows system fonts folder (e.g. by copying the pfm/pfb). Don't use fontspec but try at first with the low-level command `\font\test="[C:/Windows/fonts/XXX]" \test abc`.

Comment: I think my system works fine. I installed the fonts at home, and I can use the fonts in xetex without any problems, meaning that indeed Type 1 fonts can be directly loaded. 

Because at work I cannot install fonts for some reason, I want to use the fonts directly from disk, so that's why I'm trying this load from file method.

Comment: I think this might be a fontspec bug but I'm going on holidays soon and I won't be able to look into it until next year...

Comment: Very offtopic: Owh, you're the author of fontspec! nice to meet you :) Well have a good holidays

Comment: since you already have the .pfb file, why not just have tex generate the necessary metrics and install it the "latex way?" something like http://www.umantec.nl/fontinst/ or http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages

Comment: I have alot of bad experience with installing Fonts in the latex way, and find the fontspec package great.

Comment: If I did understand all the edits and comments correctly, you can use the fonts but your have trouble with the BoldFont=. It should be easy to get around this by using fd-definitions (like the euenc package does it for the lm-fonts). I will write the definitions tomorrow.

Comment: Uhm sorry, my question got a bit messy with all the additions, here is a summary:

(i) I'm unable to install the fonts on a particular machine, that's why I want to use fontspec to use the font diskfiles directly.

(ii) It works, however, i'm unable to declare any additional specifications such as boldfont =,italicfont =, smallcapsfont= while defining the standard font using \setmainfont[]{}. This might be a bug in fontspec as stated by Will Robertson (maintainer of fontspec if i'm correct).

Workarounds are possible by declaring newfontfamilies and using that for the bold and italic

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for not being able to install fonts on Windows: if you load them in the font viewer, other applications will be able to use them too, until you close the font viewer. I just checked, and it *is* possible to do this with Type 1 fonts: just double click on the .pfm file (which, unlike the .pfb file, will have a nice fonty icon).

Comment: well the most convenient workaround (and that is what I'm doing ) is using the font diskfiles directly, however, that usage appears to be abit buggy on my machine as I'm unable to define boldfont = and italicfont = and such when using \setmainfont{} (might be a bug in fontspec)