# Use Type 1 fonts with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, opentype, type1

I read many things about XeLaTeX and I wanted to give it a try, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make use of Type 1 fonts, in my case especially the font Lucida, which I bought from pcTeX (which don't offer OpenType, unlike TUG). In normal LaTeX it was as easy as

```
\usepackage{lucimatx}
```

I tried a solution as proposed here: [Xelatex / Fontspec how to load fonts directly from diskfile (Postscript Type 1 fonts)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/xelatex-fontspec-how-to-load-fonts-directly-from-diskfile-postscript-type-1-f)

```
\setmainfont[Path=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bh/lucida/]{lbr.pfb}
```

but this produces strange errors like

```
** WARNING ** Obsolete four arguments of "endchar" will be used for Type 1 "seac" operator.
** ERROR ** This font using the "seac" command for accented characters...
```

**Conclusion:** Is there an easy way to use Type 1 fonts with XeLaTeX?

---

MWE for the solution using `\setmainfont`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setmainfont[Path=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bh/lucida/]{lbr.pfb}
\begin{document}

Im folgendem Abschnitt wollen die Eigenschaften des Drehimpuls untersuchen,
was uns auf die \emph{Drehimpulsalgebra} führen wird. Als eine fundamentale
Eigenschaft, aus denen wir die meisten Resultate in diesem Abschnitt erzielen
werden ist, dass der Drehimpuls (angular momentum) der infinitesimale Erzeuger
der Rotation ist.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer per se to your problem, but faced with a similar desire to use the Lucida fonts with XeLaTeX I sprung for the Lucida OpenType fonts available from TUG (http://tug.org/store/lucida/opentype.html). Well worth the $90 for an individual license.

Comment: @Paul M.: Of course this is an option, but as I already stated in the question, I do own a license for Lucida Type 1 and as I'm a poor student I can't afford it twice. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I guess that begs the question -- why use XeLaTeX in the first place, if the font you want to use works perfectly fine in PDFLaTeX?  Is there a particular feature of XeLaTeX that you'd like to exploit?

Comment: The main advantage I want to make use of is, that I can type UTF-8 right away without the need to find a package which yields the desired symbol.

Comment: With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you should not get any problem with texts containing ÄäÖöÜüß and pdflatex. Of course, you must encode the files in utf-8.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the umlaut in "führen" is causing the problem. When I change your MWE as follows, it gives me a font substitution warning but otherwise compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setmainfont[Path=/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bh/lucida/]{lbr.pfb}

\begin{document}
Im folgendem Abschnitt wollen die Eigenschaften des Drehimpuls untersuchen,
was uns auf die \emph{Drehimpulsalgebra} fuhren (\verb=<-- umlaut removed=) wird. Als eine fundamentale
Eigenschaft, aus denen wir die meisten Resultate in diesem Abschnitt erzielen
werden ist, dass der Drehimpuls (angular momentum) der infinitesimale Erzeuger
der Rotation ist.
\end{document}
```

I don't know if this is a XeLaTeX bug or a problem with the Lucida Type 1 fonts.

For more info on this issue, see the following thread from the XeTeX mailing list:

http://www.mail-archive.com/xetex@tug.org/msg04433.html

Comment: Thank you for fixing that one, but unfortunately all my major documents are typeset in German, so omitting umlauts is not bearable. I think the error is due to Lucida as XeLaTeX advertises full UTF-8 compatibility.