# Combination of newtx and fontspec breaks siunitx

Tags: xetex, fontspec, siunitx, newtx

I am trying to use `newtx` and `fontspec` on XeLaTeX, and it looked OK until I used `siunitx`.
The problem is negative signs are not printed by `\num` etc.
How can I fix this?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{zxjatype} % For printing Japanese. Requires fontspec.
\usepackage[ipaex]{zxjafont} % Set Japanese font.
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-family=true,
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-mode=true,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true,
  output-quotient=\ensuremath{/},
}
\begin{document}
\textminus % OK

\num{-1e-1} % negative sign is not printed
\end{document}
```

Though my problem can be reproduced without `zxjatype` and `zxjafont`, I included them in the above example because it may be also affect my problem.

**Background**
I want to create a plot to include in my pLaTeX (Japanese LaTeX) document with a Python library `matplotlib`,
which allows you to typeset text with XeLaTeX but not pLaTeX.
Because XeLaTeX can also typeset Japanese text, I decided to use XeLaTeX to typeset Japanese in `matolotlib`.
Because my main document is written in pLaTeX, which has better support on Japanese but does not support `fontspec`, I want to use `newtxtext` on both engines.
I do not want to use `TeX Gyre Termes` or `Times` on `fontspec` because some glyphs have very different shapes compared to `newtx` (e.g. `\textmu`).

Answer (score 1):

Well you can reset the minus sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  detect-family=true,
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-mode=true,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true,
  output-quotient=\ensuremath{/},
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{
\tl_set:Nn \c__siunitx_minus_tl
            { \textminus }
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\num{-1e-1} % negative sign is not printed
\end{document}
```

[image]

But imho it is a rather bad idea to use T1-encoding as main encoding with xelatex. Quite probably more symbols will "disappear".

Comment: Namely all non-ascii characters will disappear, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102525/use-type-1-fonts-with-xelatex

Comment: @Henri Menke: Not all non-ascii characters, at least not with a T1-encoded font as in this example. But e.g. the ß will be wrong. (One can repair/add non-ascii chars with `\catcode`\ß=13 \defß{\ss}`  but it can get tiresome)

Comment: What do you mean by "more symbols will disappear"?

Comment: Well try out euro or an emdash: `€ —`. You can repair this, but you need to understand what's happening. You probably will also run into problems with copy & paste from the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `newtx`, but rather a Times-like text font

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{zxjatype} % For printing Japanese. Requires fontspec.
\usepackage[ipaex]{zxjafont} % Set Japanese font.
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279466/4427    
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\sisetup{
  detect-family=true,
  detect-weight=true,
  detect-mode=true,
  detect-inline-family=math,
  detect-inline-weight=math,
  detect-display-math=true,
  output-quotient=\ensuremath{/},
}
\begin{document}

\textminus % OK

\num{-1e-1}

$\sin(\pi/3)\approx 0.866$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @krnk Indeed, I'm just using the *math* fonts of NewTX.